# scrapy: getting banned by target website

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to extract some information from a website using scrapy(scrapy -V:1.5,Python -V:3.5) which has allowed all in its robots.txt, firstly it didn't let me crawl any link and return `INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.xxxx.com>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`,  resolve it by using useragent barely it didn't crossed 150 links, so then I managed it by using  **TOR**  and  **useragent**  together but now the problem is few links are still blocking me `[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1120 pages (at 5 pages/min), scraped 1055 items (at 4 items/min)`
any help will be greatly appriciated
TIA

```
# settings.py
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```

Comment: If a website does not wants to be crawled for data extraction then you should not do it at the first place. And it looks like this site have good system in place to block such activities which makes their intent pretty clear.

Comment: You need to use rotating proxies

Comment: @Umair i used a list of 50 free proxies, it didn't work as excpected, got myself blocked at a point...

Comment: Why you have `COOKIES_ENABLED = False` ... Set it to `True` ... Also copy exactly same request headers which your browser is using on that website.

Comment: @Umair  POST /api/v1/collector HTTP/1.1
Host: collector-pxzhh9f9x0.perimeterx.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 334
Origin: https://www.xxxx.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: https://www.xxxx.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8
Cookie: pxvid=75a7d040-2810-11e8-ba26-1b13034a2487

Comment: Copy request as cURL Bash and then convert it to Python Requests code here https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: Run that code, does that work? `print(response.status_code)` and `print(response.text)`

Comment: yeah,but response.text is none :  response.text {"do":[]}
response_code 200

Comment: Whats that? Just see the output of `print(response.status_code)` and `print(response.text)` by yourself to see if its working or not

Comment: @Umair i can get  response.text and status_code:200 from diffrent xhr and informations are available in there but with spider it is blocking me. what i am missing here so it is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using Tor is already getting you around the bans, but (of course) some percentage of the Tor exit nodes is (already) being banned (and it might get more if you are using your scraper alot).

So what you still need to do is to retry those requests that got banned.

If you are doing complex POST requests, you need to build your own retry logic. But to me it seems you are just following links, so activating retries for response code 403 should help you:

```
# settings.py

RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [403] # add here any status codes you receive when getting banned
RETRY_TIMES = 10 # depending on the percentage of blocked tor exit IPs and 
          # the amount of links you crawl you might have to increase this number
```

PS: and stay away from `COOKIES_ENABLED = True`, this can get you banned really fast as it allows the site to track your crawler across all IPs. If the site needs you to send cookies along (most don't) you'll have to use a separate cookie jar for each IP

Comment: as request credentials are same for all retry_times, it remains same 403. btw Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If there are some kind of credentials in play, it would help to see the actual code, the website URL and also what credentials were used. If some requests succeed and other fail even after retrying, the problem is not with the proxy/tor exit node IP, but with the credentials used in the requests that fail. Please provide more details.